# Trying to filter ActiveRecord has_many Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a users model, which:

`has_many :messages, -> { where('flag > ?', -99).order('posted desc') }`

Where I want any message with a flag value of -100 to be ignored. The ordering (seems) to be working, but the flag where clause does not.

Have I used this incorrectly, or am I trying to do something that's not possible?  If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-100` is not greater than `-99`, it's `1` less than `-99`.  To ignore flag value of `-100`, you could do:

```
where('flag != ?', -100)
```

Your `has_many` declaration would then be:

```
has_many :messages, -> { where('flag != ?', -100).order('posted desc') }
```

Comment: yes exactly.... -100 is LESS than -99 - so then why are messages where flag = -100, appearing if my scope is flag > -99?